# Sort the list based on multiple numeric condition using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I want to sort a list based on 3 numeric conditions. I need to do this sorting based on the property called 'CompletionPercentage'. So the list should be sorted on below conditions

1. Filter the list where the percentage should be greater than `0` and less than `100`
2. Next filter the list where the percentage is equal to `0`
3. Next filter the list where the percentage is equal to `100`

I have tried the below code but it is not working. Please help.

```
var data = myCollection
  .ToList()
  .Where(x => getCourses.CourseLevel.Contains(x.CourseLevel)
  .OrderBy(x => x.CompletionPercentage > 1 && x.CompletionPercentage < 99)
  .ThenBy(x => x.CompletionPercentage == 0)
  .ThenBy(x => x.CompletionPercentage == 100);
```

Comment: `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` are sorting operations, not filtering. If by filtering you mean "sorting", you might want to implement a custom `IComparer`. Can you clarify exactly what you want, perhaps with a worked example?

Comment: " but it is not working." can you be more precise? please post an input example, the expected output, but the most important part: the actual outcome.

Comment: what do you want to achieve, its not obvious because your words and code conflict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest *mapping* items into three groups as it's mentioned in the question:

```
.OrderBy(item => item.CompletionPercentage ==   0 ? 2
               : item.CompletionPercentage == 100 ? 3
               : 1)
```

Here we have running `item` (`CompletionPercentage > 0` and `CompletionPercentage < 100`) be the `1`st, then not started `item`s (`CompletionPercentage ==   0`) followed by completed `item`s (`CompletionPercentage == 100`)

**Code:**

```
var data = myCollection
  .Where(item => getCourses.CourseLevel.Contains(item.CourseLevel)
  .OrderBy(item => item.CompletionPercentage ==   0 ? 2
                 : item.CompletionPercentage == 100 ? 3
                 : 1)
  .ThenBy(item => item.CompletionPercentage) // if you want order per cents as well 
  .ToList();            // if you want data to be List<T>
```

Comment: Your code works fine. Thanks for your help! I tried the below piece of code which works too. But I will use code which is more readable.

`var data = myCollection.ToList().Where(x => getCourses.CourseLevel.Contains(x.CourseLevel) &&tempList.Contains(x.CompletionPercentage)).OrderBy(x => x.CompletionPercentage > 1 && x.CompletionPercentage < 100).OrderBy(x => x.CompletionPercentage == 0).OrderBy(x => x.CompletionPercentage == 100);`

Comment: @CodeLearner: in your current code: 1. `.ToList()` is premature materialization which can be dropped. 2. Do not use several `.OrderBy`, but `OrderBy` followed by `ThenBy`, `ThenBy`. 3. Be careful with ranges: `x.CompletionPercentage > 1` - what if `x.CompletionPercentage == 1`? 4. Check if `tempList.Contains(x.CompletionPercentage)` condition is actually required.